# Error in my Json file (Error: Parse error on line 176: ...1, "furnace": 1, }, "ItemListCrates" ---------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', got '}

Tags: json

Well i have a issue somewhere in my code, this is not my cup of tea to say to fix this. Ive ran through this with a fine tooth brush practically to no luck, and thought someone could tell me where on my code im doing wrong on. Code error is this once again Error: Parse error on line 176:
...1,       "furnace": 1,   },  "ItemListCrates"
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}

```
{
"ItemListBarrels": {
    "rifle.ak": 4,
    "ammo.handmade.shell": 1,
    "ammo.pistol": 2,
    "ammo.pistol.fire": 2,
    "ammo.pistol.hv": 2,
    "ammo.rifle": 3,
    "ammo.rifle.explosive": 2,
    "ammo.rifle.incendiary": 2,
    "ammo.rifle.hv": 2,
    "ammo.rocket.basic": 4,
    "ammo.rocket.fire": 4,
    "ammo.rocket.hv": 4,
    "ammo.shotgun": 4,
    "ammo.shotgun.slug": 2,
    "antiradpills": 1,
    "apple": 1,
    "arrow.hv": 1,
    "axe.salvaged": 2,
    "barricade.concrete": 1,
    "barricade.metal": 1,
    "barricade.sandbags": 1,
    "barricade.stone": 1,
    "barricade.wood": 1,
    "barricade.woodwire": 1,
    "tool.binoculars": 1,
    "black.raspberries": 4,
    "bleach": 1,
    "blueberries": 4,
    "bone.club": 1,
    "bucket.water": 1,
    "tool.camera": 1,
    "can.beans": 1,
    "can.tuna": 1,
    "candycane": 1,
    "ceilinglight": 1,
    "chair": 1,
    "chocholate": 1,
    "door.double.hinged.metal": 1,
    "door.double.hinged.toptier": 1,
    "door.double.hinged.wood": 1,
    "door.hinged.toptier": 1,
    "door.closer": 1,
    "dropbox": 1,
    "explosive.satchel": 4,
    "explosive.timed": 4,
    "explosives": 4,
    "floor.grill": 1,
    "floor.ladder.hatch": 1,
    "fridge": 1,
    "furnace.large": 1,
    "gates.external.high.stone": 1,
    "gates.external.high.wood": 1,
    "gears": 2,
    "burlap.gloves": 1,
    "glue": 1,
    "granolabar": 1,
    "grenade.beancan": 4,
    "fun.guitar": 1,
    "hammer.salvaged": 2,
    "hat.beenie": 1,
    "hat.boonie": 1,
    "bucket.helmet": 1,
    "hat.candle": 1,
    "hat.cap": 1,
    "coffeecan.helmet": 2,
    "hat.miner": 1,
    "hatchet": 2,
    "hazmatsuit": 3,
    "hoodie": 2,
    "icepick.salvaged": 2,
    "jacket.snow": 1,
    "jacket": 1,
    "ladder.wooden.wall": 1,
    "lantern": 1,
    "largemedkit": 2,
    "locker": 1,
    "longsword": 1,
    "mace": 1,
    "machete": 1,
    "mailbox": 1,
    "map": 1,
    "mask.balaclava": 1,
    "mask.bandana": 1,
    "metal.facemask": 1,
    "metal.plate.torso": 1,
    "metalblade": 2,
    "metalpipe": 2,
    "mining.quarry": 1,
    "burlap.trousers": 1,
    "pants": 1,
    "roadsign.kilt": 3,
    "pants.shorts": 1,
    "pickaxe": 2,
    "pistol.eoka": 1,
    "pistol.revolver": 2,
    "planter.large": 1,
    "planter.small": 1,
    "propanetank": 1,
    "target.reactive": 1,
    "riflebody": 3,
    "roadsign.jacket": 2,
    "roadsigns": 2,
    "rope": 1,
    "rug.bear": 1,
    "rug": 1,
    "salvaged.cleaver": 1,
    "salvaged.sword": 1,
    "weapon.mod.small.scope": 1,
    "scrap": 1000,
    "searchlight": 1,
    "semibody": 2,
    "sewingkit": 1,
    "sheetmetal": 1,
    "shelves": 1,
    "shirt.collared": 1,
    "shirt.tanktop": 1,
    "shoes.boots": 1,
    "shotgun.waterpipe": 2,
    "guntrap": 1,
    "shutter.metal.embrasure.a": 1,
    "shutter.metal.embrasure.b": 1,
    "shutter.wood.a": 1,
    "sign.hanging.banner.large": 1,
    "sign.hanging": 1,
    "sign.hanging.ornate": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.landscape": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.portrait": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.tall": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.xl": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.xxl": 1,
    "sign.pole.banner.large": 1,
    "sign.post.double": 1,
    "sign.post.single": 1,
    "sign.post.town": 1,
    "sign.post.town.roof": 1,
    "sign.wooden.huge": 1,
    "sign.wooden.large": 1,
    "sign.wooden.medium": 1,
    "sign.wooden.small": 1,
    "weapon.mod.silencer": 1,
    "weapon.mod.simplesight": 1,
    "small.oil.refinery": 1,
    "smallwaterbottle": 1,
    "smgbody": 2,
    "spear.stone": 1,
    "spikes.floor": 1,
    "spinner.wheel": 1,
    "metalspring": 1,
    "sticks": 2,
    "surveycharge": 2,
    "syringe.medical": 3,
    "table": 1,
    "techparts": 3,
    "smg.thompson": 2,
    "tshirt": 1,
    "tshirt.long": 1,
    "tunalight": 1,
    "wall.external.high.stone": 1,
    "wall.external.high": 1,
    "wall.frame.cell.gate": 1,
    "wall.frame.cell": 1,
    "wall.frame.fence.gate": 1,
    "wall.frame.fence": 1,
    "wall.frame.netting": 1,
    "wall.frame.shopfront": 1,
    "wall.window.bars.metal": 1,
    "wall.window.bars.toptier": 1,
    "wall.window.bars.wood": 1,
    "water.catcher.large": 1,
    "water.catcher.small": 1,
    "water.barrel": 1,
    "waterjug": 1,
    "water.purifier": 1,
    "furnace": 1,
},
"ItemListCrates": {
    "rifle.ak": 4,
    "ammo.handmade.shell": 1,
    "ammo.pistol": 2,
    "ammo.pistol.fire": 2,
    "ammo.pistol.hv": 2,
    "ammo.rifle": 3,
    "ammo.rifle.explosive": 2,
    "ammo.rifle.incendiary": 2,
    "ammo.rifle.hv": 2,
    "ammo.rocket.basic": 4,
    "ammo.rocket.fire": 4,
    "ammo.rocket.hv": 4,
    "ammo.shotgun": 4,
    "ammo.shotgun.slug": 2,
    "antiradpills": 1,
    "apple": 1,
    "arrow.hv": 1,
    "axe.salvaged": 2,
    "barricade.concrete": 1,
    "barricade.metal": 1,
    "barricade.sandbags": 1,
    "barricade.stone": 1,
    "barricade.wood": 1,
    "barricade.woodwire": 1,
    "tool.binoculars": 1,
    "black.raspberries": 4,
    "bleach": 1,
    "blueberries": 4,
    "bone.club": 1,
    "bucket.water": 1,
    "tool.camera": 1,
    "can.beans": 1,
    "can.tuna": 1,
    "candycane": 1,
    "ceilinglight": 1,
    "chair": 1,
    "chocholate": 1,
    "door.double.hinged.metal": 1,
    "door.double.hinged.toptier": 1,
    "door.double.hinged.wood": 1,
    "door.hinged.toptier": 1,
    "door.closer": 1,
    "dropbox": 1,
    "explosive.satchel": 4,
    "explosive.timed": 4,
    "explosives": 4,
    "floor.grill": 1,
    "floor.ladder.hatch": 1,
    "fridge": 1,
    "furnace.large": 1,
    "gates.external.high.stone": 1,
    "gates.external.high.wood": 1,
    "gears": 2,
    "burlap.gloves": 1,
    "glue": 1,
    "granolabar": 1,
    "grenade.beancan": 4,
    "fun.guitar": 1,
    "hammer.salvaged": 2,
    "hat.beenie": 1,
    "hat.boonie": 1,
    "bucket.helmet": 1,
    "hat.candle": 1,
    "hat.cap": 1,
    "coffeecan.helmet": 2,
    "hat.miner": 1,
    "hatchet": 2,
    "hazmatsuit": 3,
    "hoodie": 2,
    "icepick.salvaged": 2,
    "jacket.snow": 1,
    "jacket": 1,
    "ladder.wooden.wall": 1,
    "lantern": 1,
    "largemedkit": 2,
    "locker": 1,
    "longsword": 1,
    "mace": 1,
    "machete": 1,
    "mailbox": 1,
    "map": 1,
    "mask.balaclava": 1,
    "mask.bandana": 1,
    "metal.facemask": 1,
    "metal.plate.torso": 1,
    "metalblade": 2,
    "metalpipe": 2,
    "mining.quarry": 1,
    "burlap.trousers": 1,
    "pants": 1,
    "roadsign.kilt": 3,
    "pants.shorts": 1,
    "pickaxe": 2,
    "pistol.eoka": 1,
    "pistol.revolver": 2,
    "planter.large": 1,
    "planter.small": 1,
    "propanetank": 1,
    "target.reactive": 1,
    "riflebody": 3,
    "roadsign.jacket": 2,
    "roadsigns": 2,
    "rope": 1,
    "rug.bear": 1,
    "rug": 1,
    "salvaged.cleaver": 1,
    "salvaged.sword": 1,
    "weapon.mod.small.scope": 1,
    "scrap": 700,
    "searchlight": 1,
    "semibody": 2,
    "sewingkit": 1,
    "sheetmetal": 1,
    "shelves": 1,
    "shirt.collared": 1,
    "shirt.tanktop": 1,
    "shoes.boots": 1,
    "shotgun.waterpipe": 2,
    "guntrap": 1,
    "shutter.metal.embrasure.a": 1,
    "shutter.metal.embrasure.b": 1,
    "shutter.wood.a": 1,
    "sign.hanging.banner.large": 1,
    "sign.hanging": 1,
    "sign.hanging.ornate": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.landscape": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.portrait": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.tall": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.xl": 1,
    "sign.pictureframe.xxl": 1,
    "sign.pole.banner.large": 1,
    "sign.post.double": 1,
    "sign.post.single": 1,
    "sign.post.town": 1,
    "sign.post.town.roof": 1,
    "sign.wooden.huge": 1,
    "sign.wooden.large": 1,
    "sign.wooden.medium": 1,
    "sign.wooden.small": 1,
    "weapon.mod.silencer": 1,
    "weapon.mod.simplesight": 1,
    "small.oil.refinery": 1,
    "smallwaterbottle": 1,
    "smgbody": 2,
    "spear.stone": 1,
    "spikes.floor": 1,
    "spinner.wheel": 1,
    "metalspring": 1,
    "sticks": 2,
    "surveycharge": 2,
    "syringe.medical": 3,
    "table": 1,
    "techparts": 3,
    "smg.thompson": 2,
    "tshirt": 1,
    "tshirt.long": 1,
    "tunalight": 1,
    "wall.external.high.stone": 1,
    "wall.external.high": 1,
    "wall.frame.cell.gate": 1,
    "wall.frame.cell": 1,
    "wall.frame.fence.gate": 1,
    "wall.frame.fence": 1,
    "wall.frame.netting": 1,
    "wall.frame.shopfront": 1,
    "wall.window.bars.metal": 1,
    "wall.window.bars.toptier": 1,
    "wall.window.bars.wood": 1,
    "water.catcher.large": 1,
    "water.catcher.small": 1,
    "water.barrel": 1,
    "waterjug": 1,
    "water.purifier": 1,
    "rocket.launcher": 4,
    "flamethrower": 2,
    "flameturret": 2,
}
```

}

Comment: JSON syntax does not allow for a comma after the last item in an object or array, so remove those ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no comma allowed after the last item of a Json-object:

```
"water.purifier": 1,
"furnace": 1,  //<--Remove this comma
},

"flamethrower": 2,
"flameturret": 2,//<--Remove this comma
}
```